# pkg-config doenst show gstreamer-plugins-bad

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp, pkg-config

I am trying to write a program using rtmpsrc plugin which comes under bad plugins of gstreamer . I read article about compiling the gstreamer bad plugin programs using pkg-config tool so i tried to list all the known packages to the pkg-config on my system using "pkg-config --list-all " which doesn't include reference to gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10 at all does this mean i cant compile gstreamer bad plugin programs on my machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pkg-config --list-all will list modules you link against. gst-plugins-bad contains only plugins (like gst-plugin-ugly too) and plugins are loaded dynamically. Use gst-inspect rtmpsrc to see if the needed plugin is available on your system. In your code check the return values from functions to handle the case where elements are not installed.